# How to print "box drawers" Unicode characters in C (Linux utf8 terminal)?

Tags: c, linux, unicode

I'm trying to display Unicode characters from (Box Drawing Range: 2500–257F). It's supposed to be standard utf8 (The Unicode Standard, Version 6.2). I'm simply unable to do it.

I first tried to use the good old ASCII characters but the Linux terminal displays in utf8 and there is no conversion (symbol ?) displayed in place.

Could anyone answer these questions:

- How to encode a unicode character in a C variable (`style wchar_t`)?
- How to use the escape sequence such as 0x or 0o (hex, oct) for Unicode?

I know U+ but it seems it didn't work.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
short a = 0x2500, b = 0x2501;
wchar_t ac = a;
wchar_t bc = b;
wprintf(L"%c%c\n", ac, bc);
exit(0);
```

I know that the results are related to the font used, but I use a utf8 font (http://www.unicode.org/charts/fonts.html) and codes from 2500 to 257F must be displayed... Actually they aren't.

Thanks for your help in advance...

[EDIT LATELY]
The issue is solved since... and I found how to use wprintf() with %lc instead of %c... and deeper.
Now those bow drawers are part of my student "tools" library to make the console programming learning a little more coloured.

Comment: What kind of terminal You are using, exactly? Are You sure it uses a font that has all those glyphs? Also, You are aware of unicode <> utf-8 conversions, right? i.e. that e.g. U+2500 is 0xe29480 and e.g. U+257F is 0xe295bf? (sorry if I'm sounding harsh, but have to make absolutely sure that part is OK.)

Comment: Your question seems to imply that you don't understand the difference between unicode and unicode encodings. Your terminal probably uses utf-8 encoding, so you will have to encode your unicode code points to utf-8 encoding before sending to the terminal. That means also setting a UTF-8 locale. e.g. LANG="en_US.utf8"

Comment: Now that I think of it - Your terminal might not be running in utf-8 mode. Could You show us the output of `stty`?

Answer (score 5):

Use a Cstring containing the bytes for the utf-8 versions of those characters. If You print that Cstring, it will print that character.

example for Your two characters:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char block1[] = { 0xe2, 0x94, 0x80, '\0' };
    char block2[] = { 0xe2, 0x94, 0x81, '\0' };
    printf("%s%s\n", block1, block2);
    return 0;
}
```

prints `─━` for me.

Also, if You'd print a Cstring containing uft-8 character bytes somewhere in it, it would print those characters without problems.
/* assuming You use gcc */
And IIRC gcc uses utf-8 internally anyway.

**EDIT:** Your question changed a bit while I was writing this. And my answer is less relevant now.
But from Your symptoms - if You see one ? for each character You expect, I'd say Your terminal font might be missing the glyphs required for those characters.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you call "terminal".

The linux console uses various hacks to display unicode but in reality its font is limited to 512 symbols IIRC so it can't really display the whole unicode range and what it can display depends on the font loaded (this may change in the future).

Windows terminals used to access Linux are usually braindamaged one way or another unicode-wise.

Physical terminals are usually worse and only operate in ascii-land

Linux GUI terminals (such as gnome-terminal) can pretty much display everything as long as you have the corresponding fonts.

Are you sure you don't want to use ncurses instead of writing your own terminal widgets?